# How to know if user made an input without field listeners?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an activity with 20 `EditTexts` on it. I want to display a message if anything has been entered. Instead of attaching 20 listeners to each field, is there a way to know if input has been supplied(data changed)?

Comment: The simplest way is to attach a single `TextWatcher` to those `EditTexts` and if you see that you get text in the `afterTextChanged` method then you'll know that you have input in one of the `EditTexts`.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not involve all fields listener as stated in my question. For example, maybe a ageneral listener to activity changes? Keyboard inputs..etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a base class that takes care of notifying subclasses if any of their `EditText` widgets is being used(if any exist). Depending on what you want to do when the user inputs something you may need to change my example to suit your particular case.

Base activity from which you'll inherit:

```
public abstract class BaseTextWatcherActivity extends Activity {

    private TextWatcher mInputObserver = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            onInputChange(s.toString());
        }
    };
    private boolean mOptimize = false; 

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        View content = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, null);
        initInputsObservers((ViewGroup) content);
        mOptimize = true;
        super.setContentView(content);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) view).addTextChangedListener(mInputObserver);
        } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !mOptimize) {
            initInputsObservers((ViewGroup) view);
            mOptimize = false;
        }
        super.setContentView(view);
    }

    /**
     * Implement this method to allow your activities to get notified when one
     * of their {@link EditText} widgets receives input from the user.
     * 
     * @param s the string that was entered by the user in one of the EditTexts.
     */
    public abstract void onInputChange(String s);

    /**
     * This will recursively go through the entire content view and add a
     * {@link TextWatcher} to every EditText widget found.
     * 
     * @param root
     *            the content view
     */
    private void initInputsObservers(ViewGroup root) {
        final int count = root.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = root.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof EditText) {
                ((EditText) child).addTextChangedListener(mInputObserver);
            } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                initInputsObservers((ViewGroup) child);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then all you have to do in your activities is implement the `onInputchange` callback to let you know that the user entered something in one of the `EditTexts` from the current layout. You may want to look at the key event callbacks from the activity class for something simpler, but if I'm not mistaken those events are consumed by the `TextView`/`EditText` widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Have your TextViews all call the [addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) giving them your Activity as an argument (this). Have your Activity implement [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and override afterTextChanged().
Whenever one of the TextView changes, afterTextChanged() will be called.
Here is an idea of what your code should look like

```
public class YouActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 [...]

 textView1.addTextChangedListener(this);
 textView2.addTextChangedListener(this);
 [...]
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged (Editable s)
{
  //do something
}

}
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution that does not involve all fields listener as stated in my question. For example, maybe a ageneral listener to activity changes? Keyboard inputs..etc?

Comment: Without Listeners, you cannot know if the Views have changed.
Listening to the keyboard? An option, but you would receive a notification any time a button is pressed (not necesarely within a TextView). Is there a reason you don't want to use Listeners?

Comment: You will still get a notification for every letter being put in an edittext with the textWatcher. The reason I dont want to use  lsitener is because I have over 10 activities and each activity has edittexts and spinners.  I wanted to create base activity that all these activites extend and within that base activity "do something" that will allow me to display a message if any of of the underlying activites fields have changed