# Watch over multiple EditText for text change in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

This is what I intend to do:
I have an activity which have 20-25 EditText. When an EditText's text changes some corresponding TextView's text has to be changed. i.e. user inputs his monthly expenditure for groceries so the TextView which shows his yearly expenditure for grocery gets updated and so does the total monthly and yearly expenditure TextView.

I know that I can do it with TextWatcher.But in that case I'll need a separate TextWatcher for each of the EditText. Even if I write a custom TextWatcher which holds the EditText's Id and does the operation appropriate within a switch-case block but in that case I'll need a new instance of that class for each EditText. Isn't that very inefficient and memory consuming?

I was hoping to have something like the OnClickListener so that I would only have to Override some functions and it will do all the tasks like for all the Buttons in my Activity I just have to override the onClick(View v) function and its done. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
yourEditText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(yourFocusChangeListener);
yourEditText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(yourFocusChangeListener);

View.OnFocusChangeListener yourFocusChageListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            // Update your textview depending on which edittext lost focus
        }
    }
});
```

The benefit to this over a TextWatcher (IMO) is that you know the user is done since they have navigated away from the EditText.  The only issue is that they need to navigate away for it to fire (not sure if that would be a showstopper for you or not).

Comment: This can do obviously but I want the listener to fire right away like the TextWatcher does. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid using a `TextWatcher` to "see" the input events on your `EditText`. Some time ago I answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709597/how-to-know-if-user-made-an-input-without-field-listeners/12712094#12712094), with a small modification you could probably use it to make things easy. In that class from my answer you would probably need to modify the `onInputChange()` method to also return the id of the `EditText` so you know who triggered the text input.

Comment: can you please explain how can I get the id of the `EditText` that triggered the event?

Comment: @Mehedi the only way to have that id is to pass it to the `TextWatcher` implementation, like you already noted in your question. I've edited my previous sample to incorporate the id, you can find it here https://gist.github.com/4140851 . Don't worry about memory footprint or performance issues, those `TextWatcher` instances will not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I guess I have no other options to try other than that. I'll try it and let you know how it went.